# What should we do with an old question that still attracts attention?

Tags: discussion

A while ago, I posted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42271739/how-to-use-opencv-triangulatepoints). At this point it still seems to get some views from people who are stuck on the same or similar problems, so it would be great if it could provide some useful information. Especially since I was stuck on it for quite a while as far as I remember.

Now my situation is as follows:

- From what I remember, my solution had to do with the input data and was quite specific to my situation. I don't remember what the exact solution was, and even if I did, I don't think it would provide much value.
- I have no way to check if current and future answers work, since I finished the project a long time ago.

In this scenario, should I

- Update the question saying I can not verify or provide solutions?
- Mark the answer that seems most plausible as correct?
- Do something else?
- Do all of the above?
- Do nothing

Comment: do nothing should be an option

Comment: @Gimby fair enough